# Parsing dates with inconsistent formats in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I have two queries, both related to dates.

1) I have dates in these formats, which I'm looking to normalise into the same format before saving into a database:

- Saturday 26 July
- Monday 28 - Wednesday 30 July
- July 24th, 2014
- Thu 4 Sep
- Thu 28 Aug — Fri 19 Sep
- 24-07-2014

Single days are quite easy to work out using `strtotime()`, but ranges of dates are a bit more tricky.

This, for example, doesn't work:

```
$dateString = "Monday 28 - Wednesday 30 July";

if (strpos($dateString, "-")) {
    $datePieces = explode("-", $dateString);
    $startDate = strtotime($datePieces[0]);
    $endDate = strtotime($datePieces[1]);
} else {
    $startDate = strtotime($dateString);
    $endDate = strtotime($dateString);
}

echo '<pre>';
echo date('d F Y', $startDate);
echo '<br/>';
echo date('d F Y', $endDate);
```

Because the month is only on one side of the `explode()`, doing it this way returns:

```
01 January 1970
30 July 2014
```

2) I need a way of working out what year the date is (it will always be in the future). Something along the lines of:

```
if (the month in the date string has elapsed) {
    the year of the date is this year + 1
}
```

Comment: If you are going to get very inconsistent and non-standard formats you will have an impossible job ahead of you. You can work with dates in any format in PHP, but you *must* know the format to be able to do that. Will you know the format when processing the string?

Comment: The date strings are coming from a range of places - mainly from APIs provided by arts and cultural venues plus a dash of web scraping where no API is available. Each API / website does use it's own format consistently - the problem is that data is coming in from lots of different places.

Comment: But each place uses a consistent format? If so, you can handle this for sure. If you confirm I can show you how to do it.

Comment: Yep, each of the sources is consistent :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as each source provides you with a consistent format you can use `DateTime()` and `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to process the dates for you.

```
//Saturday 26 July
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l j F', 'Saturday 26 July');

//July 24th, 2014
$date = new DateTime('July 24th, 2014');

//Thu 4 Sep
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D j M', 'Thu 4 Sep');

//Thu 28 Aug — Fri 19 Sep
list($start, $end) = explode(' - ', 'Thu 28 Aug — Fri 19 Sep');
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('D j M', $start);
$end   = DateTime::createFromFormat('D j M', $end);

//24-07-2014
$date = new DateTime('24-07-2014');
```

I'm going to leave handling `Monday 28 - Wednesday 30 July` to you since you'll need to do a little more work to get the month from the second date and apply it to the first. But this should show you how to go about this.

Comment: That's great - thank you John! Looks like I could very easily use this as part of the API / website scraping so that everything is consistent before it goes into the database. Guessing something along the lines of `strrchr("Monday 28 - Wednesday 30 July", " ")` would work for the range of dates where the month is only mentioned once.